# I think the logo here needs revision

Tags: discussion, design

I am not a professional and famous **visual designer** but I do think the logo here seems undeveloped, dull, boring per the site's spirit. I mean, besides the term "WordPress" it seems to me unrelated to the Wordpress community..

[image]

I would want the logo and/or logo header to be more sophisticated, more sketchy, and maybe also more colorful. We could take example from the minimalist design of [GraphicDesign SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

I would also not be surprised if the current design makes people less passionate in and about the site.

I think the whole logo and logo-header, should have a serious revision by the professional visual designers of the SE team.

Comment: Please see [design tag](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) for history on the issue, there is quite a bit over years.

Answer (score 4):

I like our logo. It's plain and simple, no schnickschnack.

Besides, how would something look that is more related to WordPress? The original WP logo is a trademark of the WordPress foundation, we can't get too close to that.

Another point is: It was always important for us regulars to *avoid* the impression that we are close to the WordPress organization. While we both share some goals, like helping each other, there are also some differences.

1. Our hierarchy is much more democratic. We have moderator elections, and every member gains [moderation privileges](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) right from day one, with an influence that increases with their reputation.
2. Our content is much more focused on developer topics, and we are eager to keep it as good as possible.
3. We are not primarily a discussion site, albeit there is the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop), but focused on concrete answers to specific questions.

It's hard if not impossible to communicate these differences with visual design. But I think our current logo gives at least not opposite impression: that we are a part of wordpress.org.

For reference, here is our old logo:

> [image]

Naaah … :)

Be passionate about the content and the other people. No matter what the logo looks like.

Comment: Drupal is also a trademark and yet in Drupal StackExchange there is a nice blue drop, like in the Drupal symbol. To me it can be made more similar to the Original Wordpress logo and/or common graphics in the Wordpress organization website. Again, I am not a professional visual designer and I don't think I am the right authority to suggest any design on this.

Comment: @Benia I have added some further explanation to my answer.

Comment: I never said we should give the impression that we are part of wordpress.org nor do I think we should or advocating being less democratic (I really don't). To me the logo and logo-header are both very boring and **too far** from the Wordpress community in anything that has to do with visual design

Comment: I don't think what we currently have _is_ a logo, it's just name of the site spelled out. There _was_ a logo in last design’s initial suggestion next to it but it was critiqued off.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not a professional and famous visual designer but I do think the logo here seems undeveloped, dull, boring per the site's spirit. I mean, besides the term "WordPress" it seems to me unrelated to the Wordpress community..

This is actually intentional. When we got the first revision of our current design, it was spelt Word**p**ress and followed the Automattic Calypso colours of WordPress.com

As an Automattician I can say the likelihood of us getting permission for the trademark is low. Also remember that some stacks are exceptions. For example, https://askubuntu.com/ is not just an Ubuntu Stack, but an official site in collaboration with Canonical.

> I would want the logo and/or logo header to be more sophisticated, more sketchy, and maybe also more colorful. We could take example from the minimalist design of GraphicDesign SE.

We welcome all ideas, but the logos we've been handed by the SE design team so far haven't cut the mustard. We decided to drop the logo in favour of just the words after a large number of feedback rounds, as well as correcting the colours.

> I think the whole logo and logo-header, should have a serious revision by the professional visual designers of the SE team.

It did, that's how we got the current design. The previous one had maroon printing presses and was a bit arcane